# Hp spectre convertible x360 model15-ap012dx

Tags: bios, passwords

I got this laptop and it has no OS installed and when I try to enter bios set up to run my windows usb it asks for administrator password which I do not have. Is there a way to remove/ bypass the password or how can I reset the laptop to factory using keys??

Comment: Sounds like a stolen laptop.  I'd get your money back from the seller.

Comment: Or someone forgot they set a BIOS password three years back. Why don't you contact the seller and ask? Money back might be dicey if it's purchased from a private person.

Comment: See if this helps, read carefully>>>>https://1024kb.co.nz/bios-code-generator/#keygen